# Build specific SQL query

Tags: php, sql

please- help.
I can't handle to build the specific query.

This is the query (slighty simplified)

`$id` in this case = id_user

```
SELECT
   ARTIKELNR, ARTIKELTEXT, B_DATA,
   margin = (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(BRNTZ / WERT*100 ) FROM BEW 
             WHERE b.ARTIKELNR = a.ARTIKELNR AND USR_NR = $id )
FROM BEW b 
LEFT JOIN arb a ON b.ARTIKELNR = a.ARTIKELNR
WHERE b.USR_NR = $id 
ORDER BY B_DATA DESC
```

I have a problem with `margin` - it has to be `SUM` of two columns but, if you can see, `WERT` column cannot be equal 0 ( because `BRNTZ / WERT`). In database sometimes this column equal 0 or even `null`.

I tried `NULLIF` but i just can't build it. The best i've done is:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 SUM(BRNTZ / (WERT+0.001) * 100)...
```

Second of all, Can you tell me if it is good at all?
I am afraid that the `margin` can be taken from another `ARTIKELNR`. It's all about  `WHERE` statement.

```
margin = (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(BRNTZ / WERT*100 ) FROM BEW 
         WHERE b.ARTIKELNR = ARTIKELNR AND BEW_LIEF_KUND_NR = $id )
```

**EDIT:**

i'm usinq SQL DB
When `WERT == 0` then `SUM(BRNTZ / WERT*100 ) = 0`

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: What do you want `SUM(BRNTZ / WERT*100 )` to be if `WERT` is 0 ?

Comment: i'm usinq SQL DB

Comment: When `WERT`  = 0 then `SUM(BRNTZ / WERT*100 )` = 0

Comment: SQL DB means MS Sql Server?

Comment: yes sir, MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF() suppose to help:

```
SELECT
   ARTIKELNR, ARTIKELTEXT, B_DATA,
   IF(WERT>0, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(BRNTZ / WERT*100 ) FROM BEW 
             WHERE b.ARTIKELNR = a.ARTIKELNR AND USR_NR = $id ), 
             0
    ) as margin
FROM BEW b 
LEFT JOIN arb a ON b.ARTIKELNR = a.ARTIKELNR
WHERE b.USR_NR = $id 
ORDER BY B_DATA DESC
```

Comment: It throws me an error
`Erroneous syntax near the "IF" keyword`

Comment: @Kafus for MS SQL Server it might be the wrong answer but i don't have MS SQL Server to check it. You can try to replace "IF" with "IIF"